# How to manage SCOM 2012 notifications?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, scom

I'm looking for programmatic ways using SCOM SDK to import notifications to a third party system as well as the ability to trigger sending notifications using the API.
I've managed to find objects just as NotificationMessage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg462008.aspx), but I couldn't find something that has a method Send(Message) or something similar.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by importing notifications and triggering sending? In SCOM an alert is generated, then a notification email may be sent if a subscription has been configured.  How are you wanting to tie this into another system?

Comment: hi Jacob, it was a requirement I had to import the fields from notifications into a third party system, which in the end became importing alerts into a third party system. To resolve the sending notifications part, we create events programmatically, which in turn matches a rule and becomes an alert and then we have a subscription for those alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use develop a custom connector with the SDK.  The connector framework lets you create a custom subscription that you can select which alerts you want sent to you target system.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh329084.aspx